# Procedure has too many arguments specified

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I'm experiencing some problems in updates. I had to build my customized select and so I couldn't make dynamic queries. I've been trying to update my database using the code shown below, but I always get this error:

> Procedure or function UpdateUser has too many arguments specified.

I've filled all the arguments, no more, no less.... what's wrong?

ASPX markup:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="AllUsers" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:LocalSQL %>"
    SelectCommand="TodosOsUtilizadores" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

C# code-behind:

```
using (SqlDataSource ds = AllUsers)
{
    Guid guid = new Guid();

    try
    {
        guid = Guid.Parse(Session["user_id"].ToString());
    }
    catch 
    { 
        guid = Guid.NewGuid(); 
    }

    ds.UpdateCommand = "UpdateUser";
    ds.ConflictDetection = ConflictOptions.OverwriteChanges;
    ds.UpdateCommandType = SqlDataSourceCommandType.StoredProcedure;
    ds.UpdateParameters.Add("userid", guid.ToString());
    ds.UpdateParameters.Add("username", "Diogo");
    ds.UpdateParameters.Add("email", "user_test@gmail.com");
    ds.UpdateParameters.Add("isAnonimo", "0");
    ds.UpdateParameters.Add("isLocked", "0");
    ds.UpdateParameters.Add("roleId", "");

    ds.Update();
    DetailsView1.DataBind();
}
```

Stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].UpdateUser
    @userid nvarchar(max),
    @username nvarchar(200),
    @email nvarchar(500),
    @isAnonimo bit, 
    @isLocked bit,
    @roleid nvarchar(max)
AS
    UPDATE Memberships 
    SET Email = @email, 
        IsLockedOut = @isLocked 
    WHERE 
        UserId = CAST(@userid as uniqueidentifier);

    UPDATE Users 
    SET UserName = @username, 
        IsAnonymous = @isAnonimo 
    WHERE 
        UserId = CAST(@userid AS uniqueidentifier);

    IF (@roleid IS NULL) 
    BEGIN
        UPDATE UsersInRoles 
        SET RoleId = CAST(roleid AS uniqueidentifier);
    END;
```

Comment: Try specifying the parameters including the `@`? E.g. `.Add("@roleId", "");`

Comment: Don't [waste guids!](http://wasteaguid.info/) - `Guid guid = Guid.Empty();`

Comment: look up how to use the `Parameter.Add() Function vs the Parameter.AddWithValue() Function` you need to also specify the `DataType` the way you are using it I would change the `Add` to `AddWithValue` this way the database can handle resolving the datatype

Comment: @asawyer `new Guid()` gives you `000-000...` - still plenty left for you!

Comment: i've tried that @Blorgbeard but not worked, it says that im not specifing the parameters

Comment: @Rhumborl Well. I have learned something (That should have been blindingly obvious) today.

Comment: can you also explain why you are using `SelectCommand="TodosOsUtilizadores"` shouldn't that be the Update Command..?

Comment: nop that returns all users

Comment: I would refactor all of that code and follow a more simpler construct along with Command.Parameters.Add personally http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: yes but if i make inner joins and stuf i can't make an update

Comment: instead of using exception handling to set the guid, consider using TryParse instead (only 2 lines of code): `Guid guid; Guid.TryParse(Session["user_id"].ToString(), out guid);`

Comment: If it expects useid, which looks like you're supplying it .. then perhaps you need to step thru the code and see what the value of the GUID is ... also learn how to pass parameters properly to a Sql Object.. can you also open up the database and show us an example of what the userid field looks like as well..? also show the Schema of `Users` Table `Memberships` Table also express if those are Non Nullable fields ..you issue could be anywhere in that stored procedure.. debug this and verify

Comment: Why are you passing a guid to a varchar(max)? You should pick one datatype and stick with it.

Comment: `Sean Lange` he's using `nvarchar(max) either way I wonder why individuals neglect to provide the basics for example show us what one row in the Users Table looks like in regards to the userid field.. that's not asking too much..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with how the `SqlDataSource` works, specifically the `ConflictDetection`.

As [MSDN says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.conflictdetection(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The `ConflictDetection` property determines whether parameters for old and new values are applied to the Update method. For example, if the command that is specified by the `SelectCommand` property returns a `DataTable` object with the columns Name and Number and the `ConflictDetection` property is set to the `OverwriteChanges` value, **parameters are created for Name and Number for the `Update` method.**

So if your `SelectCommand` returns e.g. `firstname`, then there is also a `firstname` parameter already in your `UpdateCommand` and that is what is causing the errors.

Not sure if it will work, but a simple thing to try would be clearing the `UpdateParameters` collection first:

```
using (SqlDataSource ds = AllUsers)
{
    Guid guid = new Guid();
    try
    {
        guid = Guid.Parse(Session["user_id"].ToString());
    }
    catch { guid = Guid.NewGuid(); }

    ds.UpdateCommand = "UpdateUser";
    ds.ConflictDetection = ConflictOptions.OverwriteChanges;
    ds.UpdateCommandType = SqlDataSourceCommandType.StoredProcedure;

    ds.UpdateParameters.Clear();

    ds.UpdateParameters.Add("userid", guid.ToString());
    ds.UpdateParameters.Add("username", "Diogo");
    ds.UpdateParameters.Add("email", "user_test@gmail.com");
    ds.UpdateParameters.Add("isAnonimo", "0");
    ds.UpdateParameters.Add("isLocked", "0");
    ds.UpdateParameters.Add("roleId", "");

    ds.Update();
    DetailsView1.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: `Rhumbori` I think you are on to something.. I still think that this could have been resolved if the OP would just refactor the code to use `SqlConnection &&SQLCommand Object's`  and if the OP would use the Command.Parameters.Add Method overload functions properly

Comment: tried what and didn't work.. you are making a simple process harder than it needs to be `Severiano` I really don't know why you are trying to update the AllUsers this way any want when all you need to do is call a normal `StoredProcedure` from C# code and then execute the `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery` command using SqlDataClient so much easier than spinning your wheels in my opinion

Comment: ds.UpdateParameters("@userid") = guid.ToString(); ??

Comment: OK I was trying to base the answer on the original question - it is valid in actual binding scenarios. As you seem to be ignoring the data-binding side of the `SqlDataSource`, I would go with a standard SqlConnection, SqlCommand too